# Mocking a REST:Client::REST

Tags: perl, mocking, rt

I'm trying to do unit testing over an RT system, so I need to mock a RT instance locally. Basically, I'm connecting to the RT system and I'm working over the ticket's queue. Does anybody has like a code example or any ideas? I think I need to mock LWP::UserAgent but I'm not sure. 
Please ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out Test::LWP::UserAgent. It can do fairly advanced stuff. You need to look at what kind of responses you are expecting, and mock those in T::L::UA

Comment: Can we chat a little bit? If we can, please create a chat room and let me know. Thanks as usual @simbabque

Comment: Sorry, not right now. I suggest you [edit] your question to include a bit more details. What exactly are you testing? Certain endpoints, or the whole thing? If you manage to boil it down to basics, you can remove the context of RT and the question will get more attention.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Will do that.

Comment: How can I know the response I should get? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Try in production, record what it returns. If you write tests after the code and don't know the expected output, you can only trust the code. If it worked so far, it will be correct enough to start with.

Comment: Ok,for example, I wanna know the response of executing RT::Client::REST->new. How can I do that?

Comment: That doesn't do any calls. It just creates an object.

Comment: Sorry, how about login?

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Clarify your question. [Here's the directory](https://metacpan.org/source/SRVSH/RT-Client-REST-0.50/t) with the unit tests for RT::Client::REST. It sounds like you want that. If you want to know what stuff is returned by the underlying LWP::UA, read its documentation to see how to get to HTTP::Response objects while they are being processed, serialize them, and use that to build your tests. But if you want to test your RT, you should focus on building a mocked client, not writing tests for one.

Comment: Yes, I need to mock an RT, but I do not know how to do it. Do you have any example or idea?

Comment: I just told you what to do... Your question as it stands is off-topic. Please read up on documentation, try around, and ask a **specific** question when you get stuck. But this is too broad.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below my example:

```
my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('REST::Client');
my $raw_response = '';
$mock->mock(
    POST => sub { # You can do the same for GET :)
        my ($ua, $request) = @_;
        if ($request =~ /confirm/) {
            $raw_response = $confirm_response_ok; # This is response for Confirm Method in my Code
        }
        elsif ($request =~ /transfers/) {
            $raw_response = $create_response_ok; # This is response for Create transfer in my Code
        }
        return '';
    },      
    responseCode => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return '200';
    },      
    responseContent => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        return $raw_response;
    }
);
```

From Miami with Love. You know where to find us  :)

Evelio and Harold